# "Invalid recurrence rule" on some ICS files

Tags: bash, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am importing ICS files via a bash script into my GCalendar, but I am having problems with some of the files.

This is an example of payload that keeps giving me errors:

`{"summary":"Name","start":{"dateTime":"2023-02-16T14:30:00","timeZone":"Europe/Prague"},"end":{"dateTime":"2023-02-16T15:15:00","timeZone":"Europe/Prague"},"recurrence":["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240131T235959;INTERVAL=28;WKST=SU"]}`

Formatted for readability:

```
{
  "summary": "Name",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-02-16T14:30:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-02-16T15:15:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240131T235959;INTERVAL=28;WKST=SU"
  ]
}
```

For this payload I get an "Invalid recurrence rule" error. I have checked the RFC and dont see any issue with this.

Comment: You have to check the doc to see if Google Calendar understands `"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240131T235959;INTERVAL=28;WKST=SU"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - the issue was with the "WKST=SU" parameter - apparently GCal API doesnt like it

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests, and I found 2 issues with the recurrence rule. If you remove `UNTIL=20240131T235959` it works. I tried to with `UNTIL=20240131000000Z`. That one works for me.

Try using the following request:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-02-16T15:15:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-02-16T14:30:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "summary": "Name_testing",
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240131T000000Z;INTERVAL=28;WKST=SU"
  ]
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Recurrence Rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)
- [Google Documentation Recurrence rule](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#recurrence_rule)

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I tested it today and found out that Google calendar API doesnt like the "WKST=SU" parameter, it works without it

Comment: Odd, it works for me with the "WKST=SU", but it doesn't work with  `UNTIL=20240131T235959`. I also, research inside the issue tracker and I found some issues reported about that [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235489970), and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166928913), and [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232441127) too, so it might be why it works for me with the "WKST=SU" parameter.